# Ошибки underflow_error

Tags: c++

В каких ситуациях возникают ошибки из класса `underflow_error`?

Comment: ошибка обнуления; ошибка из-за потери значимости

Comment: @titov_andrei не могли бы вы привести примеры кода?

Comment: если ответ оказался полезным, проголосуйте за него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void CheckNumericLimitForAddition(int source , int summand)
{
    if ((source > (source + summand)))
    {
        throw overflow_error(MESSAGE_OVERFLOW);
    }
    else if ((source < (source + summand)))
    {
        throw underflow_error(MESSAGE_UNDERFLOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Во втором условии `else if ((source < (source + summand)))`, судя по всему, подразумевался `-`?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь непонятно, что именно имеется в виду в вопросе.

Если - что такое потеря значимости, то это одно (когда, скажем, прибавление малого числа к большому не изменяет значение этого большого числа).

Но вопрос можно понять и так - когда именно генерируется исключение `underflow_error`? И вот тут ответ совсем другой - [стандартная библиотека C++ его **не** генерирует](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/underflow_error). Другие - да, могут, например, `boost::math`, ваш код может. А вот стандартная библиотека - нет, брезгует :)